# Java String sentence - first letter uppercased, second lovercased and so on

Tags: java

Here is a description:

"Write a program that, given an input sentence, alternates the case of every alphabetic character, starting with uppercase. Spaces and non-alphabetical characters should be added to the final output as is, i.e. they should not be taken into account when alternating between upper/lowercase."

Here is what I've tried and does not work (System.out.println in main method should return correct sentence):

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(changeToUppercaseOrLowercase(countLettersWithSpaces(line), line));
    }
  }
  
  private static int countLettersWithSpaces(String sentence) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i ++)
    {
        char c = Character.toUpperCase(sentence.charAt(i));
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c == ' ' )
            count ++;
    }
    return count;
  }
  
  private static String changeToUppercaseOrLowercase(int countLetters, String sentence) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<countLetters; i++) {
          if (!sentence.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(sentence.substring(i,i+1).toUpperCase());
            }
            else {
              stringBuilder.append(sentence.substring(i,i+1).toLowerCase());
            }
          }
          if (sentence.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
            i++;
          }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }
}
```

But tests says that:

Input data:
We are the world

Expected result:
We ArE tHe WoRlD

Result:
We Re He OrLd

How to solve that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By Stack Exchange policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: It appears that removing the `i++;` inside your loop body will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Character.isAlphabetic` and keep a counter that is incremented each time a letter is encountered.

```
public static String alternateCase(String str){
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) 
           sb.append(++count % 2 == 1 ? Character.toUpperCase(c) : Character.toLowerCase(c));
        else sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Character.isLetter() function to check if it's a letter or not. half your problem will be solved.

and your problem description and test case doesnt go with each other. Please try to clarify more.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to fix this.  This one has minimal impact on your existing code.
Use an evenOdd counter to ensure you are not skipping over characters but still maintaining the alternation.

```
private static String changeToUppercaseOrLowercase(int countLetters, String sentence) {
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  int evenOdd = 0;                                  // init ********HERE*******
  for(int i=0; i<countLetters; i++) {
        if (!sentence.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
          if ((evenOdd % 2) == 0) {                 // check ********HERE*******
          stringBuilder.append(sentence.substring(i,i+1).toUpperCase());
          }
          else {
            stringBuilder.append(sentence.substring(i,i+1).toLowerCase());
          }
        }
        if (sentence.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
          stringBuilder.append(" ");
          evenOdd--;      // adjust to preserve proper alternation ********HERE*********
        } 
        evenOdd++;      // the normal update ********HERE*******
  }
  return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```